# How to Sort a List of objects by it's integer property from highest to lowest

Tags: c#

Hi I've searched for sorting technics in google but all the sorting I've tried resulted in a list starting at the lowest value to the higher, i need the list to start at the higest value to the lower...

Example Code:

```
List<OB> list = new List<OB> { new OB(5), new OB(7), new OB(3) };

//Sort Code Here

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(list[i].IntegerValue);
```

Output:

```
7
5
3
```

Comment: sort normally then reverse the list?

Comment: You could just loop through the list starting from `list.Count` down to `0`

Comment: `var list = list.OrderByDescending (o => o.IntegerValue).ToList()`?

Comment: thanks reverse is a good option

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 - Create a new, sorted list (using LINQ):

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(ob => ob.IntegerValue).ToList();
```

Option 2 - Sort the list in place:

```
list.Sort((o1, o2) => o2.IntegerValue.CompareTo(o1.IntegerValue));
```